# Always display a certain number of digits

Tags: ios, digits

I am creating a calculator app. For aesthetic reasons (numbers need to line up with an image), the result always needs to be five digits long, even if the first four digits are spaces or zeros. For example, the user enters 1+1, the result is 2, but my app should display it as "00002" or "    2".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you contradict yourself when you say the number should always be five digits long then say your app should display it as "00002" or "2". I'll assume you actually want the former? Here's a simple example assuming your number is `int x`.

```
int x = 2;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d", x];
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I achieve the same but instead of zeros it would show spaces?

Comment: It does not seem to lign up with my image underneath. It's an LCD image with dim zeros in the background. The actual UILabel are bright numbers that should line up with the zeros to create a better LCD effect. Right justification does not work...

Comment: OK, I figured it out. Just write stringWithFormat:@"% 5d" (space instead of 0) Thanks!